# Gantt chart with parent-child structure with dhtmlxgantt-with-laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, database, parent-child, gantt-chart

```
<div id="gantt-chart" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
@vite('node_modules/dhtmlx-gantt/codebase/sources/dhtmlxgantt.css')
<script src="{{Vite::asset('node_modules/dhtmlx-gantt/codebase/sources/dhtmlxgantt.js')}}"></script>
<script>
  const parentData = @json($projectOptionttmJalon); // Données des tâches parents
  const childData = @json($demandeByJalon); // Données des tâches enfants
  let taskGantt = [];
  const links = [];
  const childTasks = [];
  parentData.forEach(parent => {
    const parentId = parent.id;
    let echeance = new Date(parent.echeance);
    let debutDate = new Date(parent.debutDate);
    let diffMonth = echeance - debutDate; 
    let diffDays = diffMonth/86400000;
    
    
    const jalonId = parent.jalon_id;
    const jalon = @json($jalons).find(j => j.id === jalonId); // Faire une recherche dans le tableau des jalons pour trouver celui correspondant
    const contributors=@json($contributeurs);
    
    // Créer la tâche parent
    taskGantt.push({
      id: jalon.id, 
      text: jalon.designation,
      start_date: debutDate,
      duration: diffDays,
      progress: 0.6,
      open: true,
      jalonId: jalon.id   
    });

   
    // Créer les tâches enfants liées
   
    childData.forEach(child => {
      const deadLineNoFormat = child.deadLine;
      const deadLine = parseInt(deadLineNoFormat, 10);
      let startDate = new Date(child.date_prevue);
    
      if (child.jalon_id === jalonId ) {
        childTasks.push({
          id: `${jalonId}-${child.id}`,  // Utilisation d'un identifiant composé
          text: child.description + ', Assignée à : ' + child.contributeur,
          start_date: startDate,
          duration: deadLine,
          parent: jalonId
        });

        links.push({
          id: `${jalonId}-${child.id}`,  // Utilisation du même identifiant composé pour les liens
          source: jalonId,
          target: `${jalonId}-${child.id}`,
          type: "1"
        });
      }
    });
    console.log(childTasks);
    //taskGantt.push(...childTasks);
    //taskGantt= [...taskGantt, ...childTasks];
  });

  //console.log('task', taskGantt);

    gantt.init("gantt-chart");
    gantt.config.date_format = "%Y-%m-%d";
    gantt.parse({
      data: taskGantt,
      links: links  
    });
</script>
```

Currently, everything is working perfectly fine, but the problem I have is that I can only retrieve one child's recording. Whenever I record a new one, it replaces the previous recording. What can I do

I want a parent-child type Gantt chart, yes, I already have one, but the issue is that for the children, I can only retrieve one child. Each recording overwrites another one.

Comment: So can you please describe what have you tried so far? Also i believe you are overwriting the`childTasks` array, causing the previously created child tasks to be replaced by the new ones.

Comment: Also you can try initializing childTasks after you have initialized the parentTask `childTasks[jalonId] = []` then when the if condition is satisfied push the data to `childTasks[jalonId].push({})` and right before the gantt chart init you can merge the child tasks into the taskGantt array